# How do I debug issues with simultaneous AsyncTasks in Android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-debug

I'm running a couple of AsyncTasks at one time, it seems to be causing some peculiar issues like rendering buttons unusable. One AsyncTask takes care of keeping the session alive, and is run in onResume() on every activity:

```
public class SessionKeepAliveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private Context mContext;

    public SessionKeepAliveTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {

            ... create httpClient, set headers with cookie, 
            send request, process results     
            ...
```

Then I have another AsyncTask that is used to simply fetch a JSON object from the server and load the results into a listview:

```
public class ClaimSearchService extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String,String>, Void, Void> {

    protected Context mContext;
    private Listener mListener = null;

public ClaimSearchService(Listener listener, Context context) {
    super();
    mListener = listener;
    mContext = context;

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(HashMap<String,String>... params) {


    try {
        ...send the request, get the results, pass them to listener for 
        processing in another activity
```

If I don't run the SessionKeepAliveTask task, then my search service works as intended, but if I do, I get some unpredictable bugs. I'm more interested in knowing how I might begin to debug this issue than I am a solid answer, but obviously if anyone's run into this before that would be great. I can see current threads in the DDMS monitor but I'm not exactly sure how to utilize it.